# How to change the bits of an integer variable

Tags: variables, arduino, binary

I created an integer variable in arduino (16 bits). If I start with 0 (0000000000000000) and then I want to play bit 1 in the 9th position, for example, how do I do this without having to assign an integer value corresponding to that binary number. The programming language I'm using in *Arduino's IDE* is *C*.

Comment: You have to "assign an integer value corresponding to that binary number". Unless you have some special bit-addressable memory and special instructions to manipulate it.

Comment: This question is akin to "How do I learn to read a book without first associating letters to sounds?". Speaking of... which book are you reading?

Comment: What do you mean with "play bit 1 in the 9th position"? Bit 1 is in the second position. And how do you want to "play"? Also Arduino is **not** C!

Comment: @Sebivor: Simple answer: you don't have to. The meaning of a word is independent of how it sounds. Hearing-impaired people can very well read. (but I support what you intended to say)

Answer (score 2):

Use the bitwise assignment operators `|=` and `&=`:

```
int var = 0;
var |= (1 << 9);       // Sets bit 9
var &= ~(1 << 9);      // Clears bit 9
if ( (var >> 9) & 1 )  // Tests bit 9.
```

Comment: All of these are "assigning integer values".

Comment: That is true. But if we take OP at his word, his question is meaningless. So I assumed that he doesn't understand "assigning integer values" the same way that you and I do.

Comment: Right, and we have "close reasons" for that. The fact that we have a high-rep user just spoonfeeding answers is the wrong message to be sending in my opinion. If we just cave in to every pointless whim the site will be quickly filled with homework requests. It's clear that OP isn't putting in enough effort to learn... Please reconsider, Rob.

Comment: Note that `var &= ~(1 << 9);` fails if `var` is wider than `int/unsigned`.  Various alternative exist.

Comment: @chux Can you mention one?

Comment: @J...S `var &= ~((cast to the type of var)1 << 9);`, `var = (var | (1 << 9)) ^ (1 << 9);`,  `var &= ~((var*0 + 1) << 9);`, etc.  In some fashion the `mask` needs to be at least as wide as `var`.  Using `1u` has advantages too.

Comment: There are no "bitwise assignment" operators. Unless you overloaded them or use a custom class.

Comment: Don't answer  bad&OT questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/4774918 ask for clarification in a comment, if none shows up in reasonable time (see [ask], too), vote to close. Thanks for supporting the community.